# convert the PDF into text using MapReduce.

Tags: mapreduce, lucene, apache-pig, pdfbox, apache-tika

I am trying to convert PDF into text using Mapreduce. Please guide me for executing PDF's using Mapreduce.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to convert text to pdf without mapreduce (for example with python), you can then call the relevant (python) function from pig.

How to do this is described in the [Pig UDF manual](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/udf.html)